# Where is iOS8 document folder on Mac?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I wanted to check the document folder location of my App, but it is not in the regular location. I can not find there any iOS8 folder. Only previous iOS versions.

/Users/kukodajanos/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

[image]

Where is iOS8 Apps / document folders?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has little if anything to do with programming.

Comment: I was looking for the "document folder" the location where in iOS the app resources are stored. The other question is core data specific. Who not dealing with core data will looking for "Document folder" and will find my question and not theirs, as I was not found their question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found document folder for my App here:

> /Users/*******/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/631D6B03-25F6-4FBB-A63A-C57A5ECBBF48/data/Containers/Data/Application/F3565135-22DF-4A7B-9425-C428D65812CA/

With this line you can exactly determine, in you App also:

```
let url = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains:.UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL)
```

Here is the **location of the momd file**, if using Core Data:

> /Users/*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/631D6B03-25F6-4FBB-A63A-C57A5ECBBF48/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FC3D270A-422D-410A-A0C5-F763DD1A592A/you-app-name.app/you-app-name.momd/

And this is it how you can get your own exact location:

```
 NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("YOUR-APP-NAME", withExtension: "momd")
```